# Error 1004: Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error Excel

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I have a sub in Excel 2010 that copies information into cells. When I try to run it, I get an "application-defined or object-defined error" at:

```
With Worksheets("Parameters")
    .Range(.Cells(line + 3, amountCol), _
    .Cells(line + 3, amountCol + 6)).Copy Destination:=amounts
End With
```

This is the entire sub up to the point where the error occurs.

```
Dim numLine As Integer
Dim line As Integer
Dim allocationType As String
Dim allocationRow As Integer
Dim specialFund As Integer
Dim amountCol As Integer
Dim numCol As Integer
Dim amounts As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim costCol As Integer
Dim alloCol As Integer
Dim SFcol As Integer

SFcol = 38
alloCol = 32
costCol = 34

'set number of allocation lines
With Worksheets("Parameters")
    numLine = .Range(.Cells(3, 18), .Cells(3, 18).End(xlDown)).Count - 1
End With

'set allocation starting point
allocationRow = 3

'set the amount starting columng
With Worksheets("Parameters")
    numCol = .Range(.Cells(3, 18), .Cells(3, 18).End(xlToRight)).Count - 1
    'look for the starting year
    For line = 1 To numCol
        If .Cells(3, 18 + line).Value = Worksheets(wks).Cells(2, costCol) Then
            amountCol = line + 18
            Exit For
        End If
    Next line
End With

'go through each line, if allocation, add
For line = 1 To numLine
    With Worksheets("Parameters")
        allocationType = .Cells(3 + line, 18).Value
    End With

    'check if needs to be included
    If InStr(allocationType, Worksheets("Parameters").Cells(6, 7).Value) Then
        With Worksheets(wks)
            'format the type cell
            .Range(.Cells(allocationRow, alloCol), .Cells(allocationRow, alloCol + 1)).MergeCells = True
            .Range(.Cells(allocationRow, alloCol), .Cells(allocationRow, alloCol + 1)).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            'check if needs color
            If InStr(allocationType, "Roads") Then
                .Range(.Cells(allocationRow, alloCol), .Cells(allocationRow, alloCol + 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
            ElseIf InStr(allocationType, "Structures") Then
                .Range(.Cells(allocationRow, alloCol), .Cells(allocationRow, alloCol + 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 34
            Else
                'check if special funding color
                For specialFund = 3 To Worksheets.Count - 2
                    If InStr(allocationType, Worksheets(specialFund).Name) Then
                        .Range(.Cells(allocationRow, alloCol), .Cells(allocationRow, alloCol + 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = .Cells(2, SFcol + specialFund).Interior.ColorIndex
                    End If
                Next

            End If
            'add the allocation type
            .Range(.Cells(allocationRow, alloCol), .Cells(allocationRow, alloCol + 1)) = allocationType
            .Range(.Cells(allocationRow, alloCol), .Cells(allocationRow, alloCol + 1)).ShrinkToFit = True
            'add the amounts range
            Set amounts = .Range(.Cells(allocationRow, costCol), .Cells(allocationRow, costCol + 6))
        End With
        'copy amounts
        With Worksheets("Parameters")
            .Range(.Cells(line + 3, amountCol), .Cells(line + 3, amountCol + 6)).Copy Destination:=amounts
        End With
```

Comment: Can you include the part of the code where you define line, amountCol, and amounts?

Comment: What is `line`? can you include the part where you declare it and assign a value to it?

Comment: Does `line + 3` have an integer value of 1 or more?  Does `amountCol` have a value of 1 or more?  Is `amounts` declared as a `Range` with a value of a cell address?  On modern computers (32bit or later), `Dim amountCol as Long` is preferred.

Comment: I've added the code up to where the error occurs.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Changing it to Long fixed it. Thank you

Comment: @MechanicalNotaprogrammer.  I recommended `Long` because it is more efficient; 16bit variables require special processing on 32bit computers.  Your problem was that an `Integer` variable has a maximum value of 65535.  Your macro failed when your row number, `line`, exceeded this value.

Comment: @TonyDallimore - I suggest posting an answer, as this solved the OP.